# Can't get why I'm always redirected to https(opening my app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, https, webserver

Everything was allright, but when I started to working with SSL and run it on thin server with SSL. Tried to run different applications, but this error doesn't conect with application - it appears in all of them.

It is a little bit strange situation. In localhost my application is running, but when I added app into my remoted server and running it - it always opened as https and browser give me error:

```
  The connection was reset
```

From my console:

```
      ERROR bad Request-Line
     ERROR bad URI
```

I know, that this errors occure, when certificate has errors or some other server errors.

I checked all my config files, deleted all things connected with SSL, but it wants to open with https protocol.

Where I should search for errors ? How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just uninstalled thin server and my app started to run again.

Answer (score 0):

1. try deleting cache
2. do you have a browser extension installed that always access the https version of sites?